# What is the easiest way to run Spyder in virtual environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder

Currently, I need to open windows cmd, navigate to the environment folders directory, activate the environment of choice, and type Spyder to run Spyder in that environment. Is there any easier way to do so?

Comment: create script which will go to folder, activate environment and run spyder. But it can't give you interactive access to environment and spyder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are on windows - in `bash` you might do something like that

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/python && /path/to/venv/bin/spyder
```

For windows it looks like that:

```
call path\to\venv\Scripts\activate & call path\to\venv\Scripts\spyder
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just need to add "call" before those commands

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a working snippet for windows and wanted to know if this is correct now.